# How to allow user input batch script & parse the value to cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
title Remote Message
set /p input1= "Type the PC name: "
set pcname=%input1%
set /p input2=echo Type a message:
set msgmsg=%input2%
cmd msg /server:%pcname% */time:999 "%msgmsg%"
pause
```

Above is the batch script

how can I allow user input the pc name and the message he wanted to send remotely thru cmd? I tried 100times above code and keep modify but still not work.

Comment: remove the `cmd` command before the `msg` command (what it's supposed to do anyway?).

Comment: I often use remote desktop to user pc for troubleshooting..before I remote, I need to send a msg to user inform them...so I use cli msg

Comment: remove the cmd command before the msg will keep looping asking the input

Comment: uhh - how did you name your batch file?

Answer (score 1):

No need to set variables from variables, and please do NOT name your batch file `msg.bat` or `msg.cmd` just call it something like `send_message.cmd`:

```
@echo off
title Remote Message
set /p "pcname=Type the PC name: "
set /p "msgmsg=Type a message: "
msg /server:%pcname% */time:999 "%msgmsg%"
pause
```